# How to show integer value column to be string value in display using SQL

Tags: sql

My sale table

```
ID    Sales   Amount
--------------------
101    1      1000
102    1      1500
103    2      2000
104    3      2500
```

In the above table Sales column 1 refer  to 'keyboard' 2 refer to 'Mouse' and 3 refer to 'CD'.

If i use `SELECT * FROM Sale WHERE ID=103`

it will return

```
ID  Sales  Amount
------------------
103  2     2000
```

but I need to display like below

```
ID  Sales  Amount
------------------
103  Mouse 2000
```

In db i need to store  sales value as int like '1,2,3,4,5' but when show to user i need to display a unique string value for each integer value.

Comment: It's called a 'Join'....or use a CASE statement

Comment: Although probably not relevant for such a basic question: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I'm using SQL "How to show integer value column to be string value in display using SQL"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    CASE Sales
        When 1 Then 'KeyBoard'
        When 2 Then 'Mouse'
        When 3 Then 'CD'
    END AS Sales,
    Amount
FROM 
    Sale
WHERE  
    Id = 103
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a table like this:

```
[Table: SaleType]
+----+----------+
| Id | Name     |
+----+----------+
| 1  | Keyboard |
| 2  | Mouse    |
| 3  | CD       |
: .. : ...      :
+----+----------+
```

And set the `Sales` column in `Sale` tables a Foreign Key(FK) of `SaleType`, then you can have your result by using this query:

```
SELECT
    Sale.ID, 
    SaleType.Name, 
    Sale.Amount
FROM
    Sale
  JOIN
    SaleType ON Sale.Sales = SaleType.Id
```